# What does Toast = null mean? (android)

Tags: android

```
Toast mToast;

private void checkName() {
    if (etName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        if (mToast == null) { // Initialize toast if needed
                mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        mToast.setText("Please enter your name"); // Simply set the text of the toast
        mToast.show(); // Show it, or just refresh the duration if it's already shown
    } else {
        submit();
    }
}
```

The above program shows a toast only when it is needed. If there is a queuing of toasts, it simply ignores the toast. How does that work? What does Toast = null mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This does nothing to stop the queue of toasts, all it does it make the toast that says enter your name, and saves it in a global variable so if you need to show a toast again you dont need to recreate it. There's really no reason to do this, there is nothing wrong with creating a new toast object everytime you want to show one